# Datatables filter show duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I've 2 table and joining them in datatables server-side, but its show duplicate rows in view, what i'm mistaken

**Model :**

```
var $table = 'user_provider';
    var $column_order = array(null,'u.nm_uprov','u.email','g.nm_gprov'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('u.nm_uprov','u.email','g.nm_gprov');
    var $order = array('u.id_uprov' => 'desc'); // default order 

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->database();

    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_provider as u');
        $this->db->join('grup_provider as g','u.id_gprov = g.id_gprov');

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->M_user_provider->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $uprov) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $uprov->nm_uprov;
            $row[] = $uprov->email;
            $row[] = $uprov->nm_gprov;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_pic('."'". $uprov->id_uprov."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-fill btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_pic('."'".$uprov->id_uprov."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Hapus</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->M_user_provider->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->M_user_provider->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

**Table :**

- User provider [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU2Fa.png)
- Group Provider [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZpkC.png)

and in the bottom of table show this "Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries (filtered from 2 total entries)", i don't know what's wrong cause everything works fine except the table show duplicate rows.

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Comment: yes, i've added table structure, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding twice the table:

```
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_provider as u');
```

Try removing first "from" clause, because in the second one you add it an alias